# Django Multi-Column Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models

Is is possible to define foreign keys referencing multi columns in another model?

For example one foreign key references a two-column index in the product table, and the SQL statement:

```
FOREIGN KEY (product_category, product_id) REFERENCES product(category, id)
```

BTW I've looked into `django.contrib.contenttypes` and don't think that's the perfect solution for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not supported yet. There is a ticket and possible ways to handle it if you want to. maybe you could even run [custom sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

**Multi-Column Primary Key support**

*Relational database designs use a set of columns as the primary key for a table. When this set includes more than one column, it is known as a “composite” or “compound” primary key. (For more on the terminology, here is an ​article discussing database keys).
Currently Django models only support a single column in this set, denying many designs where the natural primary key of a table is multiple columns. Django currently can't work with these schemas; they must instead introduce a redundant single-column key (a “surrogate” key), forcing applications to make arbitrary and otherwise-unnecessary choices about which key to use for the table in any given instance.
This page discusses how to have Django support these composite primary keys. There are a lot of details to get right here, but done right, it would allow for more flexibility and potential simplicity in data modeling.*

**Current Status**

*Current state is that the issue is accepted/assigned and being worked on, and there is a partial implementation at ​http://github.com/dcramer/django-compositepks. The implementation allows having composite primary keys. However, support for composite keys is missing in ForeignKey and RelatedManager. As a consequence, it isn't possible to navigate relationships from models that have a composite primary key.*

**Discussions:**

[David Cramer's initial patch](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/eac7c296c3797f5a)

[The composite foreign key API design](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/4b2370a0652d9135)

[Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys)

Note - [SqlAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html?highlight=foreignkey#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.column) allows this as described below and you can use SqlAlchemy to replace Django's ORM

Foreign keys may also be defined at the table level, using the **ForeignKeyConstraint** object. This object can describe a single- or multi-column foreign key. A multi-column foreign key is known as a composite foreign key, and almost always references a table that has a composite primary key. Below we define a table invoice which has a composite primary key:

```
invoice = Table('invoice', metadata,
    Column('invoice_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('ref_num', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('description', String(60), nullable=False)
)
```

And then a table invoice_item with a composite foreign key referencing invoice:

```
invoice_item = Table('invoice_item', metadata,
    Column('item_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('item_name', String(60), nullable=False),
    Column('invoice_id', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('ref_num', Integer, nullable=False),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['invoice_id', 'ref_num'], ['invoice.invoice_id', 'invoice.ref_num'])
)
```

[Reference](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html?highlight=foreignkey#metadata-foreignkeys)

Comment: Really appreciate the answer and it really helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible but you will need to create a composite key when you use multiple column constraint i.e. foreign key or primary key.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
   S_num INTEGER,
   S_Cate INTEGER,
   S_descr CHAR(200),
   PRIMARY KEY (S_num, S_Cate))

CREATE TABLE sub_Student (
   Ssub_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   Sref_num INTEGER,
   Sref_Cate INTEGER,
   sub_descr CHAR(500),
   FOREIGN KEY (Sref_num, Sref_Cate) REFERENCES Student
      (S_num, S_Cate))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i'm afraid this is not the solution for the Django model i'm talking about. it is possible for a database to have composite foreign keys but it seems Django doesn't provide that kind of support yet.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can to create a "Django fixture" like this:

```
CREATE INDEX product_category_id_id ON product (category_id, id);
```

To do this, you must to create a file named `product.sql` on subfolder `sql` where your model resides. The fixture is loaded on initial syncdb.

Answer (score 0):

@pratik-mandrekar's answer is excellent, but I wanted to point out that even without proper multi-column primary keys; **django is able to accommodate queries spanning multi-column foreign keys**. Here's an example based on a legacy database who's schema I wasn't permitted to modify:

Given:

```py
from django.db import models

class Account(models.Model):
    # Collectively, location_no and occupant_no function as the primary key for Account.
    location_no = models.IntegerField()
    occupant_no = models.SmallIntegerField()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'csracct'
        unique_together = (('location_no', 'occupant_no'),)

class Call(models.Model):
    call_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    
    # Collectively, location_no and occupant_no act as a foreign key to Account.
    location_no = models.IntegerField()
    occupant_no = models.SmallIntegerField()

    notes = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'csrcall'
```

Here's how you'd use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) to fetch the 10 most recent calls for accounts with the name 'steve':

```py
calls = Call.extra(
    tables = ['csracct'],
    where = [
        'csracct.location_no=csrcall.location_no',
        'csracct.occupant_no=csrcall.occupant_no',
        'csracct.name=%s',
        ],
    params = ['steve'],
    ).order_by('-call_id')[:10]
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but `extra()` is part of django's base queryset toolkit; so it plays well with the rest of your django code. Notice how we order_by, and limit/slice the queryset using the usual django methods.